# Creating a JSON list from multiple table rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data in a BigQuery table where every row is an item in an ecommerce order, for example here are rows showing the purchase of three items across two orders:

| Order number | Product | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | ABC | 1 |
| 001 | DEF | 2 |
| 002 | GHI | 1 |

I need to create a JSON list for every *order* in the below format, which using the example data above would look like this for order 001:

`[ {product_id: "ABC", quantity:1},{product_id: "DEF", quantity:2} ]`

How can I achieve this format in BigQuery SQL?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at JSON funcs from BigQuery? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#to_json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below

```
SELECT order_number, 
  TO_JSON_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(product as product_id, quantity))) json_value 
FROM orders
GROUP BY order_number
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As @aleix-cc pointed out, this can be easily done with the [TO_JSON](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#to_json) function which is currently in preview:

```
WITH orders as (
  SELECT "001" as order_number, "ABC" as product, 1 as quantity UNION ALL
  SELECT "001", "DEF", 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT "002", "GHI", 1
 )
 

SELECT 
  order_number, 
  TO_JSON(ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(product, quantity))) json_value 
FROM orders
GROUP BY order_number
```

**Edit:** Since this is a function in preview, you should go with [Mikhail's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71845776/7903159) and use `TO_JSON_STRING`.